# How can I fix 'non-conformable arguments' error when using 'tr' as upper bound in glmnet_classifier cv.glmnet function with R packages?

Tags: r, arrays, package, glm

```
glmnet_classifier = cv.glmnet(x = emb1[tr,], y = labels[tr], 
                              family = 'binomial', 
                              alpha = 1,
                              type.measure = "deviance",
                              nfolds = NFOLDS,
                              thresh = 1e-9,
                              maxit = 1e3)
```

```r
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'drop': non-conformable arguments
```

In R package, I take the above error when I give "tr" as the upper bound of the index rather giving a static value.
How to solve that problem?

I expect to find a possible solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Comment: I could not upload the code due to the space problem

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by adding following codes  (boyut includes row and columns)   :tr <- round((boyut[1]*70)/100);
trX <- tr+1;
test <- boyut[1]-tr;
tr <- c(1:tr);
test <- c(trX:test);